# easy question about inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a,b$ be real numbers. assume them positive and $n > 0 $ is integer.

Let $a^n > b $. Say

$$ \delta = \frac{ a^n - b }{na^{n-1} } $$

Why does it follow that $0 < \delta < a$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\delta = \frac{a^n - b}{na^{n-1}}< \frac{a^n}{na^{n-1}} = \frac{a}{n} < a$